# Swagger UI not populating the response header, response body and response code

Tags: swagger-ui

The following is my swagger.json thats generated with swagger core.

```js
{
    "basePath": "/rest",
    "host": "localhost:8080",
    "info": {
        "title": "",
        "version": "1.5.0"
    },
    "paths": {
        /device/{iccid}/{deviceId}": {
            "get": {
                "consumes": [
                    "application/xml"
                ],
                "description": "Return \"Success\" if the deviceID is successfully Set \"Failure\" otherwise",
                "operationId": "setDeviceId",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "description": "iccid of the device",
                        "in": "path",
                        "name": "iccid",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "deviceId of to be on the device",
                        "in": "path",
                        "name": "deviceId",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "successful operation",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "400": {
                        "description": "Invalid status value"
                    }
                },
                "summary": "Set the deviceID of a SIM's iccid ",
                "tags": [
                    "change device name"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "schemes": [
        "http"
    ],
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "tags": [
        {
            "name": "change device name"
        }
    ]
}
```

When i curl the sample request I get the following response:

```sh
$ curl -i "http://localhost:8080/rest/device/1234555/test"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 7
Date: Mon, 31 Aug 2015 14:46:21 GMT

success%
```

I added the CORS filter in my tomcat web.xml

```xml
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I am not sure if I need more here ?

Thanks in advance.